# What is a line always pointing at 45° on a sphere like?

Tags: differential-geometry

I can easily imagine a line pointing dead vertically or horizontally on a sphere.
Say I want to draw a line which is always pointing to some degree (eg 45°) from an origin. What is this line like?
In a more realistic way to put it, I want to constantly head in a direction such as NE. How to plot it on a map? Any formula for that?
What kind of mathematical field is it?

Comment: Angle relative to what?

Comment: Also what do you mean on a sphere? On it's surface like latitude and longitude (horizontal and vertical)? Or from the center of the sphere to the surface?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: [Rhumb line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sphere to plot it and than project it on a plain. It depends what Projection or mapping  you use what you get as a curve. On the sphere it ist called a loxodrome. If you use Mercator projection it is a straight line. (It belongs to differential geometry)